# Trouble structuring classes and methods into subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to structure classes and methods using a subfolder structure as follows in Python 3.8

```
supermodule/
|_module1/
| |_module1.py (depends on module2)
|_module2/
| |_module2.py (depends on module3)
|_module3/
| |_module3.py
|_scripts/
  |_script1.py (depends on module1, module2, module3 methods)
```

I was hoping someone could explain how to overcome import errors, and how one could go about coding supermodule like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place an empty `__init__.py` file in each of the module folders.
[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: Thanks, but that should be redundant in python3 because each folder is treated as a module if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: When importing the error says `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`, even with the `__init__.py` in each directory

Comment: In both Python 2 and Python 3, the presence of `__init__.py` is what makes a folder into a package. Regarding your error, that's an issue with your code, which you haven't shown in the question.

Comment: OK thanks. is it possible to run a script in a different directory from the packages, just like in the example above?

Comment: Yes, but for that I do belive you'd have to set the sys path.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)